# Microsoft NPS 2012 R2 - Can't perform authentication from Cisco ASA with PAP

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, cisco-asa, radius, nps

I am trying to setup a Cisco ASA (version 9.1(7)6) to authenticate against a Microsoft Network Policy Server 2012 R2.

The ASA is able to communicate with the NPS server, however the `test aaa-server` command returns AAA Failure. Checking the security event log on the NPS server shows that authentication is failing because `The user attempted to use an authentication method that is not enabled in the matching network policy.` and `Authentication Type: PAP`.

What I dont understand is that `Unencrypted authentication (PAP, SPAP)` is enabled for the network policy. The server is on a fresh install of Windows and there is only a single network policy outside of the defaults. The event log entry does show it is matching my single (non-default) network policy. There do not appear to be any other relevant event log entires.

There only seems to be a problem with PAP authentication, as I am able to login via my VPN connection by authenticating against the NPS by using MSCHAPv2. As a note, the `test aaa-server` command only supports PAP authentication.

[Network Policy Authentication Methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgAVK.png)

[Event Log Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebWlT.png)

Answer (score 1):

In NPS, make sure PAP is enabled on the Connection Request Policy in addition to the Network Policy.  I had a similar problem authenticating Cisco Prime Infrastructure using PAP, so maybe my solution will be applicable to you as well.